# I'm trying to identify an IC labeled KOP9879B

Tags: power-electronics, integrated-circuit, identification

I'm trying to identify an IC labeled KOP9879B for the purpose of reparing an electronic card for an autonome lightning system that uses AC power to feel a LED bar and switch to the battery in case of power loss.

I would appreciate your help.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What led you to believe that this IC is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer is [Lii Semiconductors (力生美半导体)](https://www.liisemi.com/). The only part listed on the homepage in a SOP16 package that I can find is the [LN3206B/LN3206C](https://www.liisemi.com/index.php?m=home&c=View&a=index&aid=230).

[image]

There are no parts with a "KOP" prefix listed on the homepage as far as I can tell. Though [other homepages](http://www.sz-ccd.com/?products_35/) sell a KOP9964 and KOP9002 made by this manufacturer. All of these seem to be highly specialized MCUs, so it's probable the KOP9879B is as well.